# Python TCP Sockets: How to know if a specific connection has sent information

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a multi-threaded Python 3 application that on thread #1 accepts TCP socket communications. Thread #2 will check all current connections if they have anything to receive, then act accordingly.

So, currently I have a list called `all_connections` which is a list of accepted socket connection objects.

Using `for connection in all_connections:` I can loop through all the connection objects. I know I use `conn.recv(256)` to check if there is anything ready to recive on this socket. Will this block the loop though untill there is something to receive? I have set `conn.setblocking(1)` beforehand although Im unsure if this is the best way to get around it:

Here is some example code:

### Thread 1

```
self.all_connections = [] # init a list to hold connection objs
while 1:
    try:
        conn, address = self.socket.accept()
        conn.setblocking(1) # non blocking
    except Exception as e:
        continue
    self.all_connections.append(conn) # Save the connection object
```

### Thread 2

```
while True:
    for connection in self.all_connections:
        received = connection.recv(256)
return
```

So, I'm only interested in connections that have actually sent something, as I will be sending them something back most likely.

I know I can use `select.select` in order to check if there is anything to receive on the socket, but that wouldn't help me reference the specific connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `read()` will block; this is the default behaviour. Calling `socket.setblocking(1)` actually enables blocking, which is opposite of what you wanted. `setblocking(False)` will set non-blocking mode. I/O on non-blocking sockets requires that you use exception handling.

A better way, and you are already headed in the right direction, is to use [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/select.html#select.select). You do in fact know which socket sent data because `select()` returns a list of sockets that are available for reading, writing, or that have an error status. You pass to `select()` a list of the sockets that you are interested in and it returns those that are available for I/O. Here is the function signature:

```
select(...)
    select(rlist, wlist, xlist[, timeout]) -> (rlist, wlist, xlist)
```

So the code in thread 2 would look something like this:

```
from select import select

while True:
      rlist, wlist, xlist = select(self.all_connections, [], [])
      for connection in rlist:
          received = connection.recv(256)
```

The above code only checks for readable sockets in the list of all connections and reads data from those that are ready. The read will not block.

Comment: Plus OP doesn't have to use a separate thread for accepting new connections. This can (and should) be done in the same `select` loop. Also note that for better performance OP should switch to epoll (or some wrapper around it, e.g. gevent).

Comment: Thank you for the information on this, Just a point though, `self.all_connections` is a list of connection objects, not sockets, will this work the same?

Comment: @Harvey: in this case the connection _is_ a socket. `socket.accept()` returns a tuple containing a socket object to the newly accepted connection, and its address.

Comment: Fantastic, I will swith to using `select.select()` in my application now